# Bind keys over SSH to switch tmux tabs

Tags: ssh, putty, tmux

I typically have 4 or 5 tmux "tabs" (aka tmux windows) open.
They are created by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

In many applications you can <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between tabs (or internal windows, or whatever). You can see this in Firefox, Chrome, Sublime Text, Dolphin, etc etc etc.

How can I tell tmux to do this too?

I already tried the following in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key C-Tab next-window
bind-key C-S-Tab previous-window
```

But it doesn't work.

I am using: Windows 8.1, Putty 0.63 and tmux 1.8

Comment: I would try and solve this if it involved switching tabs in an RDP connector from an Ubuntu box, but it seems better asked on SU, since it's primarily a putty shortcut passthrough question.

Comment: Largely depends on if Putty is actually interfering or if it's an issue on a real Ubuntu system. Josh, I assume [you've seen this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470001/bind-ctrltab-and-ctrlshifttab-in-tmux) but did you also read the note about tmux only reloading its config at first start? You might need to kill all instances before it works.